# Brand new (bought today) acer travel mate's mouse stopped working after I did something (wrong!)

Tags: laptop, mouse, acer-travelmate

Today I bought an acer travel mate notebook 253M (intel core i3-3110) from amazon.de.

I clicked on something (in German) without knowing its meaning, and then the laptop's mouse is not working, it's not even showing up! Any suggestions on how can I solve this problem? What did I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've touched the `Fn` and `F7` keys together, which disabled the touchpad.  Press the key combination again to enable it.

Comment: Thanks! The mouse is back just now, and I learnt something :) Although I didn't what you mentioned, but may be did something similar. Unfortunate that I cannot remember, because I clicked on something in German which I don't remember(the laptop is bought from amazon.de